# Unable to put the azure VM into the availability zone

Tags: azure, infrastructure, azure-vm, azure-availability-zones

I need two Azure VMs into different availability zones in the US region.

However when trying to put VM into the availability zone I get an error:
[image: availability zone error]

In the azure support console, there is no way to explicitly request the "availability zone" feature.
While doing the "quota increase request" you can only change the number of required VMs, but no way to specify that the issue is caused by absence of "availability zone" permission.

I've already tried the following:

- fired 5 "quota increase request" support tickets during the last two weeks, all of them are "approved" but issue is still in place.
- contacted azure chat support, who confirmed that the issue caused by the absence of "availability zone" permission and asked to create the same "quota increase request" and describe my problem in the summary. Done, with no success
- contacted azure twitter support, who promised to escalate the "quota increase request" + add the description of the problem to it explicitly. Ticket is "approved", issue still in place.

So the question is: how do you unlock the VMs assignment to availability zone in the US East (or US East 2, or any other region).
I am sure it must be a pretty common task, I did it many times within different accounts. But on this particular new account it now seems impossible to do, and I wonder how other developers/administrators tackles this requirement.

Comment: Is your problem only with this account? What is the role of the current account, and if the role is a contributor, does the problem still exist (I chose East US and zone1 based on the contributor role here, but I did not encounter your problem.)？

Comment: My account have "owner" role in the subscription. I guess the issue is in the subscription. 
I don't experience the same issue under the another subscription, but i need to setup the infrastructure for the specific client under his subscription, unfortunately.

The question is rather about the possible ways of reaching out to azure support. I got stuck writing tickets nobody takes care about. There might be other ways to contact azure support I am not familiar with...

Answer (score 0):

I am from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. Is your issue specific to this VM size and the region? Have you tried to select a different VM size or a different region to see if you get the same error?

Can you also try to run the following az cli command and see what you get?

```
az vm list-skus --location eastus --size Standard_B1s -o table
```

Also refer to the following documentation for further details: https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable